# DataTables no carga mis datos

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy empezando con DataTables y JavaScript y acabo de implementarlo en mi proyecto. El tema es que no consigo que se carguen los datos desde mi controlador. En mi caso cargo los datos desde una función que llama a mi controlador y obtiene los registros. De lo que entendí de la lectura del manual de la página oficial de DataTables tengo el código que pongo a continuación:

HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>InfoFarma Web</title>

  <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/adminlte.min.css">
  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Datatables style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
</head>

<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row align-items-center" style="height:50px;">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnAgregar">Agregar</button>
   </div>

      <table id="tabla-usuarios" class="table table-striped table-hover" style="width:100%">
         <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>DNI</th>
            <th>Tipo</th>
            <th>Local</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="lista-usuarios">
         <!-- /.aqui jquery inserta la lista -->
         </tbody>
      </table>

</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->

  <!-- REQUIRED SCRIPTS -->
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Datatables js -->
  <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  <!-- AdminLTE App -->
  <script src="js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
  <!-- modul js -->
  <script src="js/usuarios.js"></script>
```

Y asi esta mi JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   let modo = '';
   console.log('jquery is working!');
   var ListData = GetUserList();
   var tabla_usuario = $('#tabla-usuarios').DataTable({
      "language": { "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json" },
      "data": ListData,
      "columns": [
         { "data": "id" },
         { "data": "nombre" },
         { "data": "dni" },
         { "data": "tipo" },
         { "data": "local" },
         {"defaultContent": "<button class='btnEditar btn btn-success' type='button'>Editar</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class='btnBorrar btn btn-danger' type='button'>Borrar</button>"}
     ]
   });

   // Obtener lista de usuarios
   function GetUserList() {
      $.ajax({
         url: '../controlador/UsuarioController.php?accion=listar',
         type: 'GET',
         success: function(response) {
            const usuarios = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(usuarios);  //<-aqui hago un console para ver lo que devuelve
            return usuarios;
         }
      });
      modo = '';
   }
```

Y esto es lo que se vé en el console del contenido del objeto "usuarios":

```
0: {id: "1", nombre: "EDUARDO FLORES RIVAS", dni: "07490241", tipo: "1", local: "1"}
1: {id: "2", nombre: "CARLOS ALBERTO GONZALES PRADA", dni: "03252045", tipo: "2", local: "1"}
2: {id: "3", nombre: "ANA VALLADARES RAMOS", dni: "25243044", tipo: "2", local: "1"}
3: {id: "5", nombre: "TERESA PARRA RIOS", dni: "50253624", tipo: "2", local: "1"}
4: {id: "6", nombre: "ALBERTO MORI RUIZ", dni: "40817254", tipo: "2", local: "1"}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Y así se ve el resultado:

[image: Resultado del DataTable no carga los datos]

Agradeceré cualquier ayuda para continuar con mi proyecto.

Cordiales saludos.

Comment: Según lo que leo en la [guia](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) lo que está pasando es que no estás llamando correctamente al ajax. Puesto que tu estas manejando la data via ajax. Y esto es via [servidor](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Comment: Soy yo o no se ve en qué parte asignas la respuesta de ajax al `<tbody id="lista-usuarios">` (?). Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

tienes un problema de asincronía, te explico: cuando llamas a GetUserList, se realiza un llamado a tu backend, pero este tarda en responder, mientras tanto el código continua trabajando, entonces, como tu backend aun no responde (el código se le a velocidad de micro/mili segundos) al momento en que se debe rellenar la tabla, aun no llega la información, y de hecho, aunque llegue, ya es muy tarde, la variable, al momento en que se esta ejecutando el código, esta vacía. lo que debes hacer es usar ASYNC/AWAIT de la siguiente forma:

```
$(document).ready(async function() {

    //let modo = '';
    console.log('jquery is working!');
    var ListData = await GetUserList();
    var tabla_usuario = $('#tabla-usuarios').DataTable({
        "language": { "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json" },
        "data": ListData,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "nombre" },
            { "data": "dni" },
            { "data": "tipo" },
            { "data": "local" },
            { "defaultContent": "<button class='btnEditar btn btn-success' type='button'>Editar</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class='btnBorrar btn btn-danger' type='button'>Borrar</button>" }
        ]
    });
})
    // Obtener lista de usuarios
async function GetUserList() {
    //modo = '';
    return $.ajax({
        url: '../controlador/UsuarioController.php?accion=listar',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            const usuarios = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(usuarios); //<-aqui hago un console para ver lo que devuelve
            return usuarios;
        }
    });
}
```

lo que ocurre es que await, congela a javascript hasta que llegue una respuesta de esa función. el await solo funciona dentro de funciones precedidas de la palabra async. de esta forma, tu código esperara hasta que tu backend responda y luego continuara el codigo, iniciando la instancia de datatable y rellenando los datos.

Comment: Una pregunta @Jonathan. En tu respuesta observo que en el `$(document).ready()` agregaste **async** antes de **function**. Esto es estrictamente necesario para que tu solución funcione?

Comment: si, los await solo funcionan dentro de funciones async

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!

Answer (score 1):

Excelente explicación por parte de @Jhonattan respecto a los eventos asíncronos. E incluso yo desconocía la manera en la que él lo resolvió.

Me gustaría compartirte otro par de alternativas y un tip.

**Alternativa #1:**

Si quieres continuar por la ruta en la que lo estás haciendo, otra manera es que tu función `GetUserList` regrese tu Ajax request y cuando esta haya finalizado, ahora si puedes inicializar tu jQuery DataTable. Ejemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   let modo = '';
   console.log('jquery is working!');

   //Una vez que esté resuelta la petición Ajax, se ejecutará la función done
   getUserList().done(function(response) {

       const usuarios = JSON.parse(response);
       var tabla_usuario = $('#tabla-usuarios').DataTable({
                           "language": { "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json" },
                           "data": usuarios,
                           "columns": [
                               { "data": "id" },
                               { "data": "nombre" },
                               { "data": "dni" },
                               { "data": "tipo" },
                               { "data": "local" },
                               { "defaultContent": "<button class='btnEditar btn btn-success' type='button'>Editar</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class='btnBorrar btn btn-danger' type='button'>Borrar</button>"}
                           ]
                       });
    }
});

// Obtener lista de usuarios
function getUserList() { // Un tip. En Javascript se recomienda que los nombres de las funciones sean en formato camelCase
    return $.ajax({
           url: '../controlador/UsuarioController.php?accion=listar',
           type: 'GET',
           success: function(response) {
        
           }
       });
    modo = '';
}
```

**Alternativa #2:**

En vista de que solo estás haciendo una petición Ajax de tipo **GET** al servidor para poblar la tabla, ¿por qué no aprovechar la funcionalidad **Ajax** que te da el mismo jQuery DataTable? Ejemplo:

```
var tabla_usuario = $('#tabla-usuarios').DataTable({
                       "language": { "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json" },
                       "data": usuarios,
                       "ajax":
                       {
                           "url": "../controlador/UsuarioController.php?accion=listar",
                           "type": "GET",
                           "dataType": "json",
                           "dataSrc": ""
                       },
                       "columns": [
                           { "data": "id" },
                           { "data": "nombre" },
                           { "data": "dni" },
                           { "data": "tipo" },
                           { "data": "local" },
                           { "defaultContent": "<button class='btnEditar btn btn-success' type='button'>Editar</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class='btnBorrar btn btn-danger' type='button'>Borrar</button>"}
                       ]
                   });
```

**Tip:**

Veo que tienes un par de botones para las acciones de **Editar** y **Borrar** definidas en la sección `defaultContent`. Y aunque SI es posible extraer el Id haciéndolo de esa manera, es mucho más complicado que hacerlo utilizando la propiedad `render`. Ejemplo:

```
{
   "data": null,
   "searchable": false, //el usuario no podrá buscar en este campo
   "orderable": false, //el usuario no podrá ordernar este campo
   "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
       var html = "<button class='btnEditar btn btn-success' type='button' onclick='editarUsuario(" + data.id + ")'>Editar</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
       "<button class='btnBorrar btn btn-danger' type='button' onclick='borrarUsuario(" + data.id + ")'>Borrar</button>";

       return html;       
}

//y fuera de tu $(document).ready(...

function editarUsuario(id) {
    //aquí tu código para editar al usuario
}

function borrarUsuario(id) {
    //aquí tu código para borrar al usuario
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por su tiempo y ayuda, finalmente pude lograr que cargaran los datos, a continuación el código corregido:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   let modo = '';
   console.log('jquery is working!');

   var tabla_usuarios = $('#tabla-usuarios').DataTable({
      "language": { "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json" },
      "columns": [
         { "data": "id" },
         { "data": "nombre" },
         { "data": "dni" },
         { "data": "tipo" },
         { "data": "local" },
         {"defaultContent": "<button class='btnEditar btn btn-success' type='button'>Editar</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class='btnBorrar btn btn-danger' type='button'>Borrar</button>"}
     ]
   })

   GetUserList() ;

   // Obtener lista de usuarios
   function GetUserList() {
   return $.ajax({
        url: '../controlador/UsuarioController.php?accion=listar',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            const usuarios = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(usuarios); //<-aqui hago un console para ver lo que devuelve
            usuarios.forEach(user => {
               tabla_usuarios.row.add( {
                  "id": user.id,
                  "nombre": user.nombre,
                  "dni": user.dni,
                  "tipo": user.tipo,
                  "local": user.local
               }).draw();
            });
        }
      });
   }
```

En realidad es una combinación de sus sugerencias y otras que encontré por alli.
Finalmente quedo bien:

[image: Datatable cargado]

Con toda la funcionalidad de busqueda y ordenamiento. De nuevo mil gracias.

Comment: Por nada! Para eso estamos! ;)